# Syntax error in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, soql, dynamic

```
listAccount=database.query('select id,name,BillingState,Phone,Website from Account where name Like '+searchString);
```

getting searchString value from vf page
Having Following error:

> expecting a colon, found 'sForce'
>
> Error is in expression '{!displayAccounts}' in component  in page interviewtwo: Class.InterviewTwo_Controller.displayAccounts: line 14, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has
>   been notified.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include a string in quotes, or, even better, simply use a bind variable, which reduces the odds of SOQL injection:

```
listAccount = Database.query('select name, billingstate, phone, website '+
                             'from account where name like :searchString');
```

Generally speaking, though, a query like this can be inlined, since you don't have any dynamic query stuff going on:

```
listAccount = [select name, billingstate, phone, website
              from account where name like :searchString];
```